# What is the time complexity of search () orm method in odoo?

Tags: python, orm, odoo

This method is used to search records within the model based on some condition.I want to know about time complexity of this method. How can we improve this method?

Here is an example

```
self.env["model.name"]. search ([("name","=","ABC")])
```

Is it more optimize method than raw queries?

Answer (score 2):

There is no perfect answer how much time search() ORM method takes in odoo. Some parameters affect search() method time complexity like :

- how much data is there in the model you're using search() method in
- How many search domains are applied
- How many of your domains have relational comparisons, like one2many, many2one, or many2many records compare or check
- Is there any compute field in model which is used in search domain? if yes, then have to check how complexity of that field as well.

**Easy and Fast way to fetch data** from database is to use a query but it helps only if you are using raw query data directly like in report or something. If you fetch data using query and convert it in formatted data then return to view, It might get similar time or even more time sometimes.